# Debugging the cloudflare mailchannels plugin

Tags: cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages

I am trying to use the [cloudflare mailchannels plugin](https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/functions/plugins/mailchannels/) for my cloudflare pages. But even though I set up everything exactly as described, including the Domain Lockdown, I do always get the following result:

```
Could not send your email. Please try again.
```

How can I find out what is going wrong? I can't find any log messages or other details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same problem but was able to get it working with the info provided [in this post](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/introducing-mailchannels-domain-lockdown/523913/4). I added `cfid=myproject.pages.dev` and `cfid=mycustomdomain.com` to the `_mailchannels` DNS record that you set up as part of Domain Lockdown. Originally I had followed [these instructions](https://support.mailchannels.com/hc/en-us/articles/16918954360845-Secure-your-domain-name-against-spoofing-with-Domain-Lockdown-) and used the generic workers.dev domain for my account.

Comment: Did you by any chance also figure out how to make the submitted email address the reply-to address?

Comment: @morja `personalizations: (incoming_state) => { /* ... */ return [{ /* ... */ reply_to: { name: incoming_state.formData.get("sender_name"), email: incoming_state.formData.get("sender_email"), }, }] /* ... */ }` as detailed in https://api.mailchannels.net/tx/v1/documentation

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find any proper documentation about a parameter that contains the formData...

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been stuck for months on this. I didn't realise I needed to add both the Cloudflare Pages domain and my custom domain to the DNS record. It works now.